# Free Java Swing component to view images with zoom + scroll -> wanted

Tags: java, swing

I can't seem to find a Java Swing library that I can use to *easily* display an image in a JPanel, and allow the user to scroll, pan, and zoom. Any ideas? Thanks.

I'm currently using the following code to display an image in a JPanel, but it's pretty basic.

I would really like to quickly introduce zoom, scroll and pan functionality.

```
    final BufferedImage img;

    try
    {
        img = ImageIO.read(image_file);

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new XCustomErrorClass("Could not open image file", e);
    }

    JPanel image_panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0)) 
    {
        protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) 
        {
             super.paintComponent(g);
             g.drawImage(img.getScaledInstance(getWidth()-20,-1, Image.SCALE_FAST), 10, 10, this);

        };
    };
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Oh sorry, added my current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For scrolling, put your panel into a JScrollPane.

For zooming and panning, you can transform the Graphics2D object in paintComponent according to some variables that are maintained in mouse listeners. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    // Backup original transform
    AffineTransform originalTransform = g2d.getTransform();

    g2d.translate(panX, panY);
    g2d.scale(zoom, zoom);

    // paint the image here with no scaling
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    // Restore original transform
    g2d.setTransform(originalTransform);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess it won't be too difficult to implement this. But if anyone knows of a Swing component, please suggest - reuse of existing code is a very real aspect of development IMHO